# problem debugging a android application

Tags: android, debugging

i have some problem when i want to Debug my android code. When i go to Debug as/ it says (none applicable). I have set a breakpoint though there's no blue arrow on it. Anyone who knows why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should setup your debug configuration. It should know what avd to use to launch your code on. If you're using eclipse [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html) should help.